# Product of (strongly) stable ideals and lexsegment ideals

Tags: commutative-algebra, computational-algebra

(1) Is the product of lexsegment ideals again a lexsegment ideal?

(2) Is the product of (strongly) stable ideals again (strongly) stable?

I know that both of them are false and I can find examples for (1) but I am not able to find examples for (2). Would it be possible for you to help me to find examples for (2)? (Jürgen Herzog-Takayuki Hibi, *Monomial Ideals*, problem 6.8.)

Answer (score 0):

If you have the answer for products of lexsegment ideals, then it is easy to
try a similar thing for (strongly) stable ideals, since lexsegment ideals are (strongly) stable, and sometimes their product is not even stable anymore.
If $I=(x_1,x_2)$ and $J=(x_2,x_3)$, then $IJ=(x_1x_2,x_1x_3,x_2^2,x_2x_3)$ in $K[x_1,x_2,x_3]$. Now $x_2$ divides $w=x_1x_2$, but $wx_1/x_2=x_1^2$ is not in $IJ$.

Another remark: stable (monomial) ideals have linear quotients. In the ring $K[x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4]$ the ideals $I=(x_3,x_4)$ and $J=(x_1^2x_2,x_1x_2x_3,x_2x_3x_4,x_3x_4^2)$ have linear quotients, but the product $IJ$ has not (see Conca-Herzog paper). So also the property of having linear quotients is not inherited by products.

On the other hand, the product of polymatroidal ideals is again polymatroidal (Herzog and Hibi, [Cohen-Macaulay polymatroidal ideals](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0195669805000120)).

Comment: Hi my friend.but $J$ is not strongly stable.